# Objective HTML, Google maps info window height and width

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I am using Objective HTML Google Maps i have a title getting pulled through on my map markers when they are clicked it displays the info window, how can i increase the size of the info box window because at the moment the info box is too small and i have to scroll to see all the text.

```
{exp:gmap:marker id="map" latitude="{latitude}" longitude="{longitude}" clustering="true"}
<a href="{page_uri}">{title}</a>
{/exp:gmap:marker}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to change the info window size and styling as needed.

Comment: Hi, What do i target in order to change the styling?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know off the top of my head. But let's try help you to help yourself. How do you think I would find out the name of the element to target?

Comment: Well i did not realise until now you could add your own class to the marker. I thought there might be a specific element to target in order to change the styling. This is the reason i asked.

Comment: Neither did I. :) But I would use browser debug tools to find out the ID or class of the element I wanted to change. Chrome's debug tools (web inspector) are great for this kind of thing.